# Rammed Earth Building

Tags: structural-engineering

I am estimating the amount of materials required to make a rammed earth building and I can't find anything related with the foundation of rammed earth building and about two-storeyed rammed earth building. Can you tell me about how the foundations are constructed on rammed earth building and what should be done to make two storeyed rammed earth building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the safest way is to build the foundation with reinforced concrete and leave dowels out to bond with the rebars of the rammed earth wall.

In the middle east, they have build adobe houses for centuries by combining clay and straw as a wall material. This system has proved to have excellent thermal properties, but not sufficient strength for earthquakes.

They used to mix lime with sand and silt and clay as primitive concrete for the foundation.

There is no code for the rammed earth construction. So every individual needs to hire an engineer to do the calculations and prepare the plans for them. here are some photos that were taken during the construction.

[source](http://www.rammedearth.info/rammed-earth-pictures-page-3/#Pictures)

[image: foundatn]

Comment: Good answer. See this wiki link for more information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rammed_earth